# Exception while reading from Excel

Tags: java, excel, exception, apache-poi

I'm encountering with this problem while reading from .xlsx file 
This is the error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.util.POILogger.log(I[Ljava/lang/Object;)V
```

Given the following source:

```
try (FileInputStream file = 
    new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\MBBF.xlsx"))) {
        XSSFWorkbook workbook1 = 
            new XSSFWorkbook(file); // Error occurs here
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook1.getSheetAt(0); 
        .....
```

Comment: Did you [try following the instructions in the Apache POI FAQ Entry that's pretty much exactly your error message](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10006)? And if not, why not?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using wrong version of Apache POI.Please upgrade to latest version 
if possible.

Comment: I'm using version 3.13 it supports xssf, it is simple reading task but fails though. I just dont get why.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18231134/how-to-avoid-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-apache-poi-util-ioutils-copyljava

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31580826/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-illegalaccesserror